# Separate quaternion 1 and quaternion 2 away from each other by amount of degrees?

Tags: game-physics, quaternions

How can I separate quaternion 1 and quaternion 2 away from each other by amount of degrees?

`<--q1q2--> to   <--q1---q2-->`

I have tried slerp with a interpolate value of 1.1 - which is the correct direction. But I need to update the quaternions by a fixed set value. Otherwise the distance between q1 and q2 increases exponentially between every update.

**Edit:**
When looking at it in a single axis: `Q1<-20°->Q2` after *somehow* changing Q2 - it goes or becomes Q3 mentioned in the answer: `Q1<-30°->Q2orQ3` when wanting to separate one of the involved quaternions with 10°. Note this has to be in the correct direction/slerp direction mentioned.

My problem could be described as trying to add collision physics to game objects which rotates around the user - so that they don't overlap and cover each other. While at the same time moving away from their original position as little as possible.

My need is to have the game objects at the same rotation from the user to stop stacking - and form clusters instead. So that every object can be seen and interacted with.

I am using [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.quaternion?view=netframework-4.8) C# `Quaternion`

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:
0) say you have Q1 and Q2, and want Q3 10 degrees from Q1 towards Q2:
1) get the angle between Q1 and Q2.
2) Q3.w = Q1.w * cos(10deg) / cos(angle)
3) Q3.x = Q1.x * sin(10deg) / sin(angle)
4) same for Q3.y and Q3.z.

You would have to check for Q1 = Q2.

I can add a javascript (using the three.js library) if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to clarify even more in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Apart(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2)
{
    var angle = Calc.ToRad(0.4f);
    var vector = new Vector3(1, 1, 0); // new Vector(1, 1, 1) if 3d probably!
    someObj1.Orientation = q1 * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(vector, angle);
    someObj2.Orientation = q2 * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(vector, -angle);
}
```

This results in stacked objects animating apart - creating a diagonal line of objects in my mobile app which visualises objects given by the their `Orientation` on the screen in 2D.

So seperating only in one axis:
`var vector = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);`
means: `<OO> . <O-O> .. <O--O>` on each update

---

**Edit**:

Actually the `vector` had to be decomposed and angle multiplied in all axises separately.

```
// where UnitX is (1, 0, 0) and UnitY (0, 1, 0)
someObj1.Orientation = q1 * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, xAngle) * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitY, yAngle); 
someObj2.Orientation = q2 * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, -xAngle) * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitY, -yAngle);
```

As I needed to separate with a specific angle and in 2D I could simply take percentages out of the that angle:

```
var angle = Calc.ToRad(0.4f);
var makePortions = new Random().NextDouble();
var xAngle = (float)(angle * makePortions);
var yAngle = (float)(angle * (1 - makePortions));
```

Otherwise angle changes in X axis would stop take effect on the objects orientation in around 180 deg Y axis orientations.